# ServiceWorker source headers

Tags: javascript, http-headers, response-headers, service-worker

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js');
```

How can I retrieve the `/service-worker.js` headers without initialising an extra AJAX request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing in the service worker spec that provides for this. [You can get the url](https://slightlyoff.github.io/ServiceWorker/spec/service_worker/index.html#service-worker-url) from the `registration` object, but I don't see anything about headers.

They are [planning to add a special expiration header](https://github.com/slightlyoff/ServiceWorker/issues/721) for service workers in the future, so maybe it will eventually make sense to expose headers on the registration as well.

Unless there's a non-service-worker-specific way to do this, I think you're out of luck.